# Low/high-frequency estimates in $\mathrm{L}^\infty$ for Lipschitz nonlinearities

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz nonlinearity with $f(0) = 0$ and suppose $u \in \textrm{H}^s(\mathbb{R}) \cap \textrm{L}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ for some $s \in [0, \tfrac{1}{2}]$. Given some threshold frequency $\xi_0$, define the operators
$$
u_{\textrm{low}} := \mathscr{F}^{-1}(1_{\{ |\xi| < \xi_0 \}} \widehat{u}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad u_{\textrm{high}} := \mathscr{F}^{-1}(1_{\{ |\xi| \geq \xi_0 \}} \widehat{u}).
$$
Do any of the estimates
$$
\| f(u)_{\textrm{low}} \|_\infty \lesssim \| v \|_\infty \qquad \text{or} \qquad \| f(u)_{\textrm{high}} \|_\infty \lesssim \| v \|_\infty
$$
hold, where $v$ is one of $u_\mathrm{low}$, $u_\mathrm{high}$ or $u$?

Comment: Excluded $f(x) = ax + b$ functions.

Comment: Why do you expect the estimate to be linear? if $f(u)=u^2$ for instance, a simple rescaling $u\mapsto tu$ shows that both estimates are impossible.

Answer (score 1):

When $f$ is the constant function, the first claim can't possibly hold (I assume $f(u) is the composition?)

Comment: $f(u)$ is the composition. Sorry, I only meant that $v$ is _one_ of $u_\mathrm{low}$, $u_\mathrm{high}$, $u$, not _all_ of them. Updated the question.

Comment: When $f$ is constant, $f(u)_\textrm{low}=f$ is independent of $u$ and so cannot be bounded by anything that only depends on $u$.

Comment: Somehow I read $f = \mathrm{identity}$ … Anyway, thanks for the observation—I never intended constant outer functions to be included as Lipschitz nonlinearities ;) Have updated the question once more.